# Angular unit testing: Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

This error is occurring when I try to instantiate the setup phase of my unit test.  I am unit testing a directive, which has its own controller.  For best practice purposes I can always add the `controllerAs` property to the directive to assign the controller a name, but I get the same error if I do that anyway.

```
describe('myDirective', function() {        

    beforeEach(module('app'));
    beforeEach(module('app/directives/directive.html'));

    var theArgs = { 
        arg1 : [],
        arg2 : 'id',
        arg3 : [],
        arg4 : '',
        arg5 : false
    };  

    beforeEach(inject(function($templateCache, _$compile_, _$rootScope_, $controller) {
        template = $templateCache.get('app/directives/directive.html');
        $templateCache.put('app/directives/directive.html', template);
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        scope.args = theArgs;
        ctrl = $controller({
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    it('should compile', function() {
        var myElement = angular.element('<div my-directive args="theArgs" ></div>');
        var element = $compile(myElement)(scope);

        // Grab scope. Depends on type of scope.
        scope = element.isolateScope() || element.scope();
        // Grab controller instance
        controller = element.controller(ctrl);
        $rootScope.$digest();        

        // Mock the directive's controller's add() function
        scope.add();                
     });    
});
```

The error is occurring within this block:

```
ctrl = $controller({
    $scope: scope
});
```

Since the controller doesn't have a name, I am not passing it one in the above code block.  That shouldn't throw an error by itself though, right?  I don't think there is a problem with my karma configuration since my other 500 tests are all passing.

The second error is being thrown at `controller = element.controller(ctrl);`, where it can't find the `ctrl` variable.  That error makes sense because it's caused by the first error, but I can't figure out how to fix the first error.

**UPDATE: Added directive code to show how the controller was defined.  It was never assigned a name, it is anonymous, and I didn't use the controllerAs property, because it returns an error.**

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    var dirController = ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.add = function() { ... };
    }];

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            args: '='
        },
        templateUrl: '/path/to/template.html',
        controller: dirController
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem is exactly with this code section:

```
ctrl = $controller({
    $scope: scope
});
```

Since `$controller` is require the name of the controller for the first parameter, and then the injectables afterwards within an object literal.
E.g.: Tell it which controller should it create:

```
ctrl = $controller('MyControllerName', {
    $scope: scope
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I add a name I get a different error: `Argument 'myController' is not a function, got undefined`.

Comment: what is your controller name? Can you show me how did you implemented that part?